# What does 1 Timothy 5:9 mean about not admitting widows under sixty years old? Was it to the church back then? And why?

Tags: 1-timothy, gender

In 1 Timothy 5:9 (KJV) it states:

> Let not a widow be taken into the number under threescore years old, having been the wife of one man."

What does the age of a widow have to do with her desire or capability for serving God?

Comment: This is where simply reading a few verses before and after the verse in question would cause it to evaporate. Simple context provides all the biblical hermemeutical consideration necessary. This is about the fellowship serving the material needs of widows who are truly deserving of practical help.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the context of the passage, especially verses 4, 8 and 11 of the chapter, Paul is referring to placing widows on a list to be supported by the church.  In other words, these elderly widows were without family to care and provide for them.